# echo [9876543210] displays 1 4 5 6 ... why?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, echo, patterns

Please explain why 1 4 5 6 is displayed for the last four echo statements?  I hit this by accident once, but I am now curious as to why this behavior occurs.

These statements work as expected (for me).

```
$ echo [ 9876543210 ]  
[ 9876543210 ]

$ echo [237890]  
[237890]
```

These echo statements consistently display 1 4 5 6.  Is there something special about these numbers?

```
$ echo [9876543210]  
1 4 5 6

$ echo [abcd9876543210ghi]  
1 4 5 6

$ echo [-123456-]  
1 4 5 6

$ echo [-7654321-]  
1 4 5 6
```

Thanks!

- The possible duplicate is related and helpful, but not a duplicate. The possible duplicate is from the perspective of an `rm` command. This question is from the perspective of a perceived "weird behavior" of an `echo` command. The underlying answer for both is globbing. Someone searching for issues with an `echo` command would not easily find the `rm` question, but would more likely land here.

Comment: you have 4 files in your current directory, named: `1` `4` `5` and `6`

Comment: Note that if you turn on `nullglob`, your second example (`echo [237890]`) will actually print nothing, which could have been a clue that you were seeing glob-expansion in the other examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working of rm/ls with \[0-9\]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68941/working-of-rm-ls-with-0-9)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The open bracket `[` is a special character to the shell; it opens up a pattern matching algorithm that says "match any of the characters inside the brackets". Because you have 4 files named as: 1, 4, 5, and 6 in your current directory, when the characters inside the brackets contain any of those digits, your shell replaces the pattern-match with those filenames. When you instead use `echo [ 9876543210 ]` you are calling echo with 3 parameters: `[`, `9876543210`, and `]`.

You should quote your echo statement's parameters to prevent the shell from seeing it as a pattern matching request.

```
$ echo '[9876543210]'
[9876543210]
```

(or remove the files named 1, 4, 5, and 6 -- but that's a workaround to demonstrate the behavior, not a fix).

Comment: The key point is that the argument to `echo` is interpreted differently by `bash` depending on whether or not there are spaces between the square brackets and what's inside them. `[123]` vs. `[ 123 ]`.