# ${p:2:1} Meaning in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, variable-substitution

Can anyone tell me the meaning of `${p:2:1}` in shell scripting as in:

```
var1=""
for p in [1,2,3,4]
do
    var1="${var1} ${p:2:1}"
done
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be what you're asking about, so I'll just comment here: using `[1,2,3,4]` in the `for` loop means that `p` gets assigned a single value: `[1,2,3,4]` instead of what you *might* have meant: the list `1 2 3 4`, which you would do with `for p in 1 2 3 4 ...`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, even worse if you have a file called `1` in the current directory

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @ilkkachu, and good point!  (Or even a file named `,`!)

Comment: Related to the above discussion: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347950/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller Iterating over the list `1 2 3 4` would make the substitution `${p:2:1}` a bit pointless as it would be empty... But then again, iterating over a single string is also a bit pointless.

Comment: Indeed; the actual point of the `for` loop may be a different question, but I wanted to point out the possible misunderstanding as a separate point from the "expansion" question from the title.

Answer (score 9):

That is a [parameter expansion (Bash manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), in particular of the form:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

which is described as "substring expansion". It extracts characters from the variable starting at `offset` (starting at zero) and going for `length` characters. In your case, `${p:2:1}` extracts the third character.

Example:

```
$ p=abcd
$ echo "${p:2:1}"
c
```

Comment: Happy to hear, Siddhartha! Welcome to the site. Don't forget to take our [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn a badge, then take a moment to absorb the answers to your question and accept the one that you feel is the best solution. That helps the U&L system separate "answered" from "unanswered" questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's a substring. It's taking from the second character (counting from 0) of the string `p` a substring of length 1.

Comment: I'm new to this can you please explain in detail