# How to use character classes

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

In one of my systems, when I run `ls [:lower:]*`, it will list all files that start with a lowercase letter.

In another one, it will give an error:

```
ls: cannot access [:lower:]*: No such file or directory
```

There are files that start with a lowercase in the working directory.

Running `ls [[:lower:]]*` instead, will work on both systems. I'd like to understand why `ls [:lower:]*` does not work in the second system and what is the proper way to use character classes.

Both are running Bash, but I would like an answer that I can apply to other shells as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example didn't do what you thought it did; it instead listed all the filenames that started with any one of the following characters:

- `:`
- `e`
- `l`
- `o`
- `r`
- `w`

(those are the letters of `lower`, re-sorted).  To use a character class, you must already be within the square brackets *and then* use `[:lower:]`, as in your second example.

Comment: Doh! Confess you laughed at me :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Not at all, actually! It helps to have [seen this sort of thing before...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347950/117549)