# what should echo [:space:] print?

Tags: bash, echo

What should commands `echo [:space:]`  and `echo [:alpha:]` print on bash terminal? The behavior seems pretty random.

Sometimes it just prints the whole strings `[:space:]` or `[:alpha:]`, at other times they expand to some (but not all) single character file names in the directory.

Comment: Sounds a bit like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347950/117549 to me

Comment: thanks. checking it out

Comment: Are you sure that you typed the command into the question properly?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes. and the behavior is very inconsistent. echo [:space:]  prints a and s and echo [:alpha:] prints a. I have files a s and t in the directory, among other multi character name files.

Comment: The linked question doesn't answer my question completely

Comment: `echo [:space:]` will output the names of any files whose names are the single character `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c`, or `e`. More interesting is `echo [[:space:]]`, which will output the names of files whose names consist of a single character of whitespace in your locale (typically, tab, LF, VT, FF, CR, or space.).

Comment: Does it always do the same thing?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes just realized that! thanks!

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I typed what I was trying on my computer. But I get it now it's doing what it's supposed to do. for the glob expansion I should have used [[..]] instead of [..] which will just use the characters inside. Thanks!